# Making your Help Guide Google-able

Tags: seo, chm, user-guide

We currently have a big user guide that can be either a raw chm file or just hosted in a webpage. We are wanting to get to the point that Google indexes all the items inside help guide so someone can just google it and it would come up.

Has anyone tried this type of mass SEO of their user guide/help guide? Any tips?

Comment: [Note: General SEO questions are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time ago I put some stuff (web help created by FAR HTML) online. A Google search found a match (see attached snapshot). OK not really a new note.

A table of contents, an index and e.g. a search button is recommended for web help too. Please have a look at http://helpware.net/FAR/help/hh_start.htm and try the “Search” button. Something you already have online ...

Uploading your web help content to a subdomain e.g. www.knowledgebase.YourCompany.com may be a one part of a solution for you. Use Google’s webmaster tools for uploading a sitemap about this subdomain content.

Google’s Custom Search is another idea. For further information please have a look at: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

[image]